# Bulk editing image links

Tags: notepad++, sublimetext3

How can I remove the -300x433 before `.jpg` :

```
http://www.mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/soho-300x433.jpg
```

To:

```
http://www.mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/soho.jpg
```

The problem: I need to remove different size not necessary -300x433 from all my links.

Comment: Is the image size always separated from the name by a hyphen (`-`)?

Answer (score 0):

You can. Both notepad++ and sublime text support regex search and replace.

Notepad++:

```
CTRL+H
Search Mode: Regular Expression
Search: (.*)\D\d+x\d+(\.jpg)
Replace: $1$2
```

Sublime Text:

```
CTRL+H
ALT+R (Select Regular Expression)
Search: (.*)\D\d+x\d+(\.jpg)
Replace: $1$2
```

The regex above looks like this:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

It searches for two numbers of at least one digit (`\d+`) separated by an `x` character. `\D` is the inverse of `\d`, so this also replaces the first non-number character as well.

`$1` and `$2` are the capture groups. They add back in anything matched by the patterns in the brackets (`.*` and `\.jpg` in this case).

Answer (score 0):

I'd do (with Notepad++):

Find what: `-\d+x\d+(?=\.jpg)`
Replace with: `Empty string`